# Using min/max conditional formula and create new column in data frame

Tags: r

The goal here is to create a fourth column which will assess via a formula if the highest of y or z is higher than x, which will produce a result of "1" ... otherwise "0".

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1000:1004, 
                 y = c(900, 950, 1050, 1100, 1000), 
                 z = c(500,1000,2000,2500,1000))
df[,4] <- ifelse(max(df$y,df$z) > df$x, 1, 0)
df[,4] <-ifelse(max(df[,2], df[,3]) > df[,1], 1, 0 )
```

I'm getting various results... sometimes only one number is displayed. In other instances, the entire vector (column) is passed to the min/max formula and not the single row (the row is compared to the column/vector, not just the other matching rows).

Can anyone help write this formula using min/max to help me avoid using longer if/or/and formulas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use `pmax` to get the rowwise max between 'x', 'y' and then do thee comparison with `z`.  Note that `ifelse` is not required here, as the logical `vector` can be coerced to binary with `as.integer`

```
df$newCol <- as.integer(with(df, pmax(y, z) >= x))
```

Similarly, if it needs to be based on `min`, it would be `pmin` instead

Comment: akrun, very handy to know! Thanks. I might need the ifelse anyway because the actual formula (conditionals) is more complicated, but that wasn't the issue for me!

Comment: @dwdionis  Okay, if you have nested `ifelse`, then `case_when` is also an option

Comment: `as.integer(max.col(df[c("x", "y", "z")]) != 1)`

Comment: @d.b. One edge case would be when all the values are same in a row

Comment: @akrun. changing min/max to pmin/pmax worked perfectly, keeping all else the same.

Comment: That's true. I think both are giving same result right now but you could change yours to `as.integer(with(df, pmax(y, z) >= x))` if necessary

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `mutate` from `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 mutate(new_column = as.numeric(pmax(y, z) > x))


     x    y    z new_column
1 1000  900  500          0
2 1001  950 1000          0
3 1002 1050 2000          1
4 1003 1100 2500          1
5 1004 1000 1000          0
```